# How can I set the textcolor of the ContentPresenter in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

These days I am coding a Control which will use in Xamarin.

The control contains a `ContentPresenter` that you can set a text or control as its child.

I want to set the textcolor of the ContentPresenter.

In WPF, there is a `TextBlock.Foreground` property in ContentPresenter which can achieve this easily. However, Xamarin has not this property.

How can I set this? Thank you.

Comment: No, there is no such property in Xamarin. You can set the text color of the child control instead.

Comment: Will you mark if I write an answer so that we can help more people with same problem?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Yes, I will mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such property in Xamarin.

You can set the text color of the child control instead.

Refer: [contentpresenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.contentpresenter?view=xamarin-forms)